# Variation between C# and Java when converting long to byte array

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I'm not experienced in Java and so this is going straight over my head:-

Java Code:

```
long foo = 1234567890;
byte[] boo = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(foo).array();
```

C# Code:

```
long foo = 1234567890;
byte[] bar = BitConverter.GetBytes(foo);

// reverse to match Java's Big Endianess
byte[] boo = bar.Reverse().ToArray();
```

In the Java sample, boo = 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, -106, 2, -46

However in C#, boo = 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 150, 2, 210

Can someone with a bigger brain, explain why these differ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java is using signed bytes, C# is using unsigned. Note that all values < 127 match, and values > 128 are converted to a negative number. If you converted the C# array from `byte` to `sbyte`, the values would match.

Comment: Exactly. The corresponding data type in C# is `sbyte` (signed byte).

Comment: More specific: for values > 127 the Java value is the C# value subtracted by 256.

Comment: Shouldn't have deleted my answer :) This is what I wrote. Have an upboat!